# UITextView Inside UITableViewCell Auto-Layout iOS 6 vs. iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm building a messaging screen as part of the app I'm writing. Currently, it is a `UITableView` containing cells that are my own custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I am using auto layout with constraints on the cell defined in Interface Builder. My messaging mimics, or attempts to mimic, the default messaging app. There are three main components of each table view cell: a `UITextView` containing the message body and two additional `UILabel`s, one for the sender's name and/or time stamp, and the other for delivered/read receipts.

Now, using auto layout combined with `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on my view controller, the message's text view in each table view cell is supposed to grow according to how large the message is (I use `sizeWithFont:constainedToSize:lineBreakMode` at present - I know it's deprecated but the replacements don't work on iOS 6 and are also flaky as of yet). This works fine when both labels and the text view are all present on the UI. However, in an individual message thread, I remove the delivered/read label using `removeFromSuperview` for all message cells but the final message (if said final message is sent by you). This does not cause adverse affects on iOS 7, but on iOS 6, any cell that has a label removed causes the text view to have a height of `0.0` (confirmed by debug outputs). Programmatically re-adding the label and appropriate auto layout constraints seems to fix it, but in any cell where that label is removed, even if I calculate a positive height for the text view in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, the text view height is zero, and the remaining label ends up shifted upwards to 'appear' to overwrite the text view.

I guess removing a view from its superview is the main culprit here, but I don't understand why this would occur only on iOS 6 instead of both 6 and 7.

Now, the code. Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * sentMessageCellIdentifier = @"sentMessageCell";
    static NSString * receivedMessageCellIdentifier = @"receivedMessageCell";

    MessageCell * cell;
    Message * messageObject = [associatedThread.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    GroupMember * selfMm = [associatedThread.parentGroup groupMemberForUser:[ApplicationInstance getInstance].currentUser];

    if ([messageObject.sender isEqualToGroupMember:selfMm]) {
        // Sent
        cell = (MessageCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sentMessageCellIdentifier];
        cell.sentTimeLabel.text = [UtilityFunctions messageFriendlyFormattedDateTimeForDate:messageObject.messageTime];
        if ([messageObject isEqualToMessage:[associatedThread.messages lastObject]]) {
            cell.deliveredReadByLabel.text = @"Sent";
        } else {
            cell.deliveredReadByLabel.text = nil;
        }
    } else {
        // Received
        cell = (MessageCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:receivedMessageCellIdentifier];
        [cell setSenderAndDateTimeForSender:messageObject.sender date:messageObject.messageTime];
    }

    // Read by label
    NSString * readByText = nil;
    if (associatedThread.parentGroupMember == nil) {
        // Group thread
        if (messageObject.readBy.count == 0) {
            if (![messageObject.sender isEqualToGroupMember:selfMm]) {
                 readByText = @"Read by: only you";
            }
        } else {
            NSInteger readByCount = messageObject.readBy.count;
            NSInteger toSubtract = [messageObject.sender isEqualToGroupMember:selfMm] ? 1 : 2;
            if (readByCount == associatedThread.members.count - toSubtract) { // If everyone read it (minus you and the sender)
                readByText = @"Read by everyone";
            } else {
                GroupMember * randRbm = [messageObject.readBy firstObject];
                if (messageObject.readBy.count == 1) {
                    cell.deliveredReadByLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Read by: %@", randRbm.user.displayName];
                } else if (messageObject.readBy.count > 1) {
                    cell.deliveredReadByLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Read by: %@ + %d", randRbm.user.displayName, messageObject.readBy.count - 1];
                }

                cell.deliveredReadByLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [cell.deliveredReadByLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapReadByLabel:)]];
            }
        }
    } else {
        // One-on-one individual thread
        if ([messageObject isEqualToMessage:[associatedThread.messages lastObject]] &&
            [messageObject.sender isEqualToGroupMember:selfMm]) {
            if (cell.deliveredReadByLabel.superview == nil) {
                [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.deliveredReadByLabel];
                // Auto-layout bindings
                NSArray * constaints = @[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.deliveredReadByLabel
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:cell.sentTimeLabel
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:1.0],

                                         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.deliveredReadByLabel
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:cell.contentView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:20.0],

                                         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.deliveredReadByLabel
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:cell.contentView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:-20.0],

                                         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.deliveredReadByLabel
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:cell.contentView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                       constant:-5.0]
                                         ];

                [cell addConstraints:constaints];
            }

            if (messageObject.readBy.count == 1) {
                readByText = @"Read";
            }
        } else {
            [cell.deliveredReadByLabel removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    if (readByText != nil) {
        cell.deliveredReadByLabel.text = readByText;
    }

    debugLog(@"%@", [messageObject isEqualToMessage:[associatedThread.messages lastObject]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    debugLog(@"x,y [%f, %f] | w,h [%f, %f] - message view", cell.messageView.frame.origin.x, cell.messageView.frame.origin.y, cell.messageView.frame.size.width, cell.messageView.frame.size.height);
    debugLog(@"x,y [%f, %f] | w,h [%f, %f] - sent time label", cell.sentTimeLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.sentTimeLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.sentTimeLabel.frame.size.width, cell.sentTimeLabel.frame.size.height);
    debugLog(@"x,y [%f, %f] | w,h [%f, %f] - sender time label", cell.senderAndDateTimeLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.senderAndDateTimeLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.senderAndDateTimeLabel.frame.size.width, cell.senderAndDateTimeLabel.frame.size.height);
    debugLog(@"x,y [%f, %f] | w,h [%f, %f] - delivered label", cell.deliveredReadByLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.deliveredReadByLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.deliveredReadByLabel.frame.size.width, cell.deliveredReadByLabel.frame.size.height);

    // Message body
    [UtilityFunctions setZeroInsetsForTextView:cell.messageView];
    cell.messageView.text = messageObject.messageBody;
    cell.messageView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    cell.messageView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    CGFloat totalHeight = 0.0;
    Message * m = [associatedThread.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Top and bottom padding
    totalHeight += 5.0 + 5.0;

    // Height + padding between labels (and text view)
    totalHeight += 14.0 + 14.0 + 1.0 + 1.0; // height + height + padding + padding

    // Modify UI slightly if incoming message and one-on-one thread:
    if (associatedThread.parentGroupMember != nil) {
        totalHeight -= (14.0 + 1.0);
        if ([m isEqualToMessage:[associatedThread.messages lastObject]]) {
            if ([m.sender isEqualToGroupMember:[associatedThread.parentGroup groupMemberForUser:[ApplicationInstance getInstance].currentUser]]) {
                totalHeight += (14.0 + 1.0);
            }
        }
    }

    NSString * bodyText = m.messageBody;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(MESSAGE_TEXT_WIDTH_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize sizeWithFont = [bodyText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    totalHeight += sizeWithFont.height + 1.0; // 1.0 because iOS hates me

    if ([m isEqualToMessage:[associatedThread.messages lastObject]]) {
        debugLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        debugLog(@"NO");
    }

    debugLog(@"height: %f", totalHeight);

    return totalHeight;
}
```

Here are the constraints I set in Interface Builder. Note the static width of the message text view:

[image: Auto layout constraints]

And here is how it looks in iOS 6 (notes: the colors are for my own visual aid, it obviously will not stay that way, and simulator/device produces same results):

[image: iOS 6]

Here is the expected behavior in iOS 7, as I desire it to behave:

[image: iOS 7]

It's important to note the the height of the actual table view cell itself appears to be correct, but the text view is not adjusting accordingly, despite being able to I've tried adjusting my code in both methods above and attempted different techniques to no avail. I'm fairly certain that I need to use `removeFromSuperview` as that is the only way to both use auto layout and accommodate what I am trying to do. The delivered/read label gets removed under the following conditions:

- There are two people in the message thread
- The message is the latest message in the thread
- That last message was sent by you

I know this is a terribly specific question, but if anyone has ideas as to why this occurs I would be grateful. Note that the text view is not editable, though it is selectable.

As always, thanks.

Edit: I also occasionally will get iOS 6 to throw `Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCell layoutSublayersOfLayer:]` even though my custom subclass doesn't implement that function. It has whined about constraints before, but that is a crap shoot to reproduce that error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by giving in and just keeping both `UILabel`s on the cell at all times. I'll just be clever about how I arrange the date and read bys. I'll leave this in case someone has a similar issue in the future.